# Forest Land Remaining Forest Land, Emissions Algorithm

Tags: co2, emissions

I'm trying to understand how CO<sub>2</sub> emissions are calculated in the Land Use category "Forest Land Remaining Forest Land". There are several subcategories, the one with the biggest impact seems to be "Change in Biomass" both above and below ground and I would like to understand this subcategory.

I came to this as a bit skeptical of the large negative values (i.e. forests are absorbing large amounts of CO<sub>2</sub>) being quoted in various government reports and I would like to have a rough understanding how this number is calculated.

The clearest reference I have found is from [climate-policy-watcher](https://www.climate-policy-watcher.org/emission-factors/change-in-biomass-carbon-stocks-aboveground-biomass-and-belowground-biomass.html) but I would like to understand a bit better.

Is the idea of Equation 2.8 in that linked page, that one should first estimate properties of the existing forest and also the "Biomass Expansion Factor", then one assumes that the existing forest will grow according to this factor? It seems from reading the related section on how to estimate the BCEFS, that it is always positive and related to growth of a tree.

However I find that this leads to the conclusion that every forest just expands naturally, which seems pretty odd. Certainly if I compute the total existing forest cover and multiply it by some positive factor, I will come to the conclusion that the forest is expanding and absorbing carbon, but I'm pretty skeptical that this is accurate. Don't most forest just reach  steady state in general? Aren't there many non-anthropogenic factors which limit the growth of a forest, so that one cannot estimate the biomass growth of a forest just from the natural growth of a tree?

Comment: The climate-policy-watcher link seems to be an incomplete reproduction of the Chapter 2 of the 2006 IPCC guidelines for the land use-related emissions [https://www.ipcc-nggip.iges.or.jp/public/2006gl/vol4.html].